GTK 3: How can I share one GLContext across multiple GLAreas?
I'm currently creating an app with multiple OpenGL windows that draw very similar things. With Cocoa and Win32, I am creating a dummy window, then creating an OpenGL context and passing that context to every real window I create.
How can I also do this in GTK? I have tried different two ways of creating a GdkGLContext:

gdk_window_create_gl_context()
gtk_gl_area_get_context()

I then return the GdkGLContext from the GLArea::create-context signal.
However, this results in the window being transparent and visually glitchy. What is the correct way to do this?
